Decidability of {M | M accepts some x in less than |x| steps}
Is this language decidable?
{M | M accepts some x in less than |x| steps}
It feels like it should be undecidable but I can't think of a good proof that isn't similar to that of Rice's theorem (which I don't think applies here because this isn't a property of a language). Does rice's apply? Or is there a way to decide this?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121152/161641

Rice's theorem doesn't apply because your language isn't semantic.
Let's call your language $L$, and assume that both $M_1$ and $M_2$ accept $\Sigma^*$ for some input alphabet $\Sigma$.
$M_1$ directly accepts all inputs, but $M_2$ always reads the whole string and then accepts.
Then $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$ but $\langle M_1 \rangle \in L$ whereas $\langle M_2 \rangle \notin L$.

Remember, that
$$A_\varepsilon = \{\langle M \rangle : M \text{ is a TM that accepts } \varepsilon\}$$
is undecidable.
We now try to show that $A_\varepsilon \leq_m L$, from which follows that $L$ must be undecidable as well.
Proof:
For a TM $M = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, F)$ define $M' = (Q, \Sigma', \Gamma', \delta', q_0, F)$, where

$\Sigma' \cap (\Sigma \cup \Gamma) = \emptyset$,
$\Gamma' := \Sigma' \cup \Sigma \cup \Gamma$, and
$\delta'(q, a) = \begin{cases}
\delta(q, \square) & \text{if } a \in \Sigma' \\
\delta(q, a) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$, where $\square \in \Gamma$ denotes the blank symbol.

$M'$ essentially behaves like $M$, except that it ignores all of it's input characters, it treats them like $\square$.
So the computation of $M'$ on any input is basically the same as $M$ on $\varepsilon$.
Now, if $M$ accepts $\varepsilon$ in $n$ steps, then $M'$ accepts every word $x \in \Sigma'^{n + 1}$ in $n$ steps as well.
If $M$ doesn't accept $\varepsilon$, then $M$ accepts nothing.
Therefore
$$\langle M \rangle \in A_\varepsilon \iff \langle M' \rangle \in L$$
which implies that $A_\varepsilon \leq_m L$.

There is a notion of Time constructible functions $T: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that requires a restriction of $T(n)\leq n$. This is usually encountered while Turing machines are first defined in textbook (page 16, Arora & Barak).
The key idea is to allow a Turing machine to atleast read the input string $x$. This will require atleast $|x|$ steps. After that the machine may either output 0 or 1 as result.
As per OP,

{M | M accepts some x in less than |x| steps}

The Turing machine is not given enough time to read the input.

So are you claiming this makes it undecidable or decidable? How can we be certain that the TM doesn't suddenly start accepting all strings longer than some arbitrarily long length?
